# Select specific node next to another - C# - SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

I have an XML file that have two nodes with same name, and need to validate if the first one exist. I'm trying to do with SelectSingleNode and I found some XPath examples.

XML File

```
<root>
    <header/>
    <mensagem>
        <header/>
        <operacoes>
            <operacao>
                <titulo>
            </operacao>
            <operacao>
                <titulo>
            </operacao>
        </operacoes>
    </mensagem>
    <trailer/>
</root>
```

Code

```
XmlDocument arquivoXml = new XmlDocument();
arquivoXml.Load(arquivo.ToString());

if (arquivoXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("root/header") != null)
{
    // Tryed the condition above with XPath "../header" too
    // If first header does exists
}
else
{
    // If first header does not exists
}
```

The condition always do the same result if I remove one or another  node. How can I validate the existence of an specific one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your XML, I think you want to check

```
if (arquivoXml.SelectSingleNode("root/header") != null)
```

or

```
if (arquivoXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("header") != null)
```

You do not even need XPath but could use

```
if (arquivoXml.DocumentElement["header"] != null)
```